# Script to get all users (local and AD) member of the local administrators group

Tags: active-directory, powershell, local-system

I need a script to get local and AD users having admin rights on a server >= Win 2008r2
The output should be something like:

```
type   username
----   ----------------
local  administrator
AD     zakkojo
...
```

I can get local administrartors members with
powershell:

```
PS>Get-LocalGroupMember

ObjectClass Name                      PrincipalSource
----------- ----                      ---------------
User        DOMAIN\bak.windows        ActiveDirectory
Group       DOMAIN\Domain Admins      ActiveDirectory
Group       DOMAIN\ad_ops             ActiveDirectory
User        SERVENAME\Administrator   Local
```

(win2008r2 and 2012 have no principalsource attribute)

or using batch with  "net localgroup administrators"

But how can i get users in nested groups?

Comment: `Get-LocalGroup | Get-LocalGroupMember |
    ForEach-Object {
        $_;
        if ( $_.ObjectClass -eq 'Group' ) {
            $_.SID | Get-LocalGroupMember -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
        }
    }` gives raw output with duplicities…

Comment: thx @JosefZ for your suggestion, but what i need to obtain is a list of users (local or from AD) that can access to the machine with admin rights.